# Can't get coveralls.io to work with Travis CI and jest

Tags: jestjs, travis-ci, coveralls

I can't get Travis CI and local builds to send coverage information to coveralls.io. Travis CI and my local machine builds was successfully capture in coveralls.io, but coverage still show nothing (0% coverage).
Here is my  [GitHub repo](https://github.com/koonfoon/generator-vscode-typescript-jest), [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.com/github/koonfoon/generator-vscode-typescript-jest) and [coveralls.io](https://coveralls.io/github/koonfoon/generator-vscode-typescript-jest) page.

Here is how my "script" value look like in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "pretest": "eslint .",
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "test:coveralls": "jest --coverage && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js && rm -rf ./coverage",
    "test:coverallsLocal": "jest --coverage && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js"
  },
```

And here is my travis.yml file

```
language: node_js

node_js:
  - node

install:
  - npm ci --no-optional

script:
  - npm run test:coveralls

after_success:
  - echo -e "Test Success"
```

Including verbose option for coveralls. Here is the result:

```
> generator-vscode-typescript-jest@0.2.19 test:coverallsVerbose
> jest --coverage && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | coveralls -v
PASS __tests__/app.js
  generator-vscode-typescript-jest:app
    ✓ creates files (1 ms)
  console.warn
    yeoman-test: question website was asked but answer was not provided
      at CustomDummyPrompt.Object.<anonymous>.DummyPrompt.run (node_modules/yeoman-test/lib/adapter.js:43:15)
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.4 s
Ran all test suites.
[debug] "2021-03-06T07:10:40.095Z"  'TN:\n' +
  'SF:../../home/travis/build/koonfoon/generator-vscode-typescript-jest/generators/app/index.js\n' +
  'FN:8,(anonymous_0)\n' +
  'FN:51,(anonymous_1)\n' +
  'FN:60,(anonymous_2)\n' +
  'FN:102,(anonymous_3)\n' +
  'FNF:4\n' +
  'FNH:4\n' +
  'FNDA:1,(anonymous_0)\n' +
  'FNDA:1,(anonymous_1)\n' +
  'FNDA:1,(anonymous_2)\n' +
  'FNDA:1,(anonymous_3)\n' +
  'DA:2,1\n' +
  'DA:3,1\n' +
  'DA:4,1\n' +
  'DA:5,1\n' +
  'DA:7,1\n' +
  'DA:10,1\n' +
  'DA:18,1\n' +
  'DA:51,1\n' +
  'DA:53,1\n' +
  'DA:54,1\n' +
  'DA:62,1\n' +
  'DA:66,1\n' +
  'DA:70,1\n' +
  'DA:74,1\n' +
  'DA:82,1\n' +
  'DA:92,1\n' +
  'DA:97,1\n' +
  'DA:98,1\n' +
  'DA:99,1\n' +
  'DA:103,1\n' +
  'LF:20\n' +
  'LH:20\n' +
  'BRF:0\n' +
  'BRH:0\n' +
  'end_of_record\n'
[debug] "2021-03-06T07:10:40.096Z"  'user options undefined'
[debug] "2021-03-06T07:10:40.103Z"  'No valid .coveralls.yml file found'
[debug] "2021-03-06T07:10:40.127Z"  {
  service_name: 'travis-ci',
  service_number: '33',
  service_job_id: '488741007',
  service_pull_request: 'false',
  run_at: '2021-03-06T07:10:40.101Z',
  git: {
    head: {
      id: 'HEAD',
      committer_name: 'koonfoon',
      committer_email: 'koonfoon@gmail.com',
      message: 'trigger travis ci build 3.09pm +semver: skip',
      author_name: 'koonfoon',
      author_email: 'koonfoon@gmail.com'
    },
    branch: 'master',
    remotes: [ [Object] ]
  }
}
[debug] "2021-03-06T07:10:40.129Z"  'in: ' ''
[info] "2021-03-06T07:10:40.133Z"  'sending this to coveralls.io: ' '{"source_files":[],"git":{"head":{"id":"HEAD","committer_name":"koonfoon","committer_email":"koonfoon@gmail.com","message":"trigger travis ci build 3.09pm +semver: skip","author_name":"koonfoon","author_email":"koonfoon@gmail.com"},"branch":"master","remotes":[{"name":"origin","url":"https://github.com/koonfoon/generator-vscode-typescript-jest.git"}]},"run_at":"2021-03-06T07:10:40.101Z","service_name":"travis-ci","service_number":"33","service_job_id":"488741007","service_pull_request":"false"}'
[debug] "2021-03-06T07:10:41.263Z"  200
[debug] "2021-03-06T07:10:41.264Z"  '{"message":"Job #33.1","url":"https://coveralls.io/jobs/76252693"}'
The command "npm run test:coverallsVerbose" exited with 0.
cache.2
store build cache
after_success
0.00s$ echo -e "Test Success"
Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

This section at the start of lcov.info file:

```
'SF:../../home/travis/build/koonfoon/generator-vscode-typescript-jest/generators/app/index.js\n'
```

is always a absolute path, I think it should be relative path, like:

```
'SF:generators/app/index.js'
```

But how to make a relative path?

Here is the [link](https://travis-ci.com/github/koonfoon/generator-vscode-typescript-jest/builds/219188071) to the build

Comment: Have you tried the verbose mode suggested in [troubleshooting](https://docs.coveralls.io/troubleshooting)?

Comment: Hi, @jonrsharpe. I did what you advise and here is the [result](https://travis-ci.com/github/koonfoon/generator-vscode-typescript-jest/builds/219188071). I notice the `'{"source_files":[]` has a empty array. I think it suppose has value in it. But how? Configure jest setting?

Comment: If you have a solution, please add an answer below rather than including it in the question - you can leave it un-accepted to indicate you’re still looking for others.

Comment: Found a work around [here](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/pull/771), it is not the solution that I am hoping for, but it will work for now. Basically just use linux ```sed``` command to replace the ```SF:``` with the correct path.